# how to reflection mybatis mapper to persist different entity in one place in java 8

Tags: java, java-8, mybatis

Now I want to write some public field into different table using Mybatis in Java 8, what I want to do not using reflect would like this:

```
private void calcSingle(Entity appListRecord,AppListMapper mapper){
                appListMapper.updateByPrimaryKeySelective(envelopeAppList);
    }
```

but I have write many same dulplicate code like this, now I want to write once like this:

```
    private void calcSingle(T appListRecord,E mapper){

   // pass different entity and using reflection to invoke the methond updateByPrimaryKeySelective method(each mapper invoke the same method)
        }
```

then I could using one function and pass different entiry and mapper to avoid copy code. what should I do to archive this? any suggestion?

Comment: It's not clear how MyBatis is involved, but perhaps the  generic method signature needs to be something like: `void <T> calcSingle(T record, Mapper<T> mapper)`.

Answer (score 0):

do like this:

```
Method method = mapper.getClass().getMethod("updateByPrimaryKeySelective", envelopeAppList.getClass());
method.invoke(mapper, envelopeAppList);
```